# Retrieving spcecific JSON values related to a loop

Tags: javascript

I'm making a browser based game which involves a map. To render the map I am using two loop to retrieve the map data from a json set. The json set looks like this (Example):

```
var map = {
'y1':{'x1':{'type':'grass'}, 'x2':{'type':'water'}, 'x3':{'type':'grass'}},
'y2':{'x1':{'type':'grass'}, 'x2':{'type':'water'}, 'x3':{'type':'grass'}},
'y3':{'x1':{'type':'grass'}, 'x2':{'type':'water'}, 'x3':{'type':'grass'}},
'y4':{'x1':{'type':'grass'}, 'x2':{'type':'water'}, 'x3':{'type':'grass'}},
'y5':{'x1':{'type':'grass'}, 'x2':{'type':'water'}, 'x3':{'type':'grass'}}
};
```

There is two loops. One with the variable `i`, which is associated with the Y axis, and `ii`, which is associated with the X axis. How would I get the json data with the tag like `map.yi.xii.type`? I've been trying to do this for days but I'm very new to json and can't find any answers. The code for my map is below. Any help would be appreciated. If I've been unclear please let me know and I'll try and give a better explanation.

```
var create = '';
for(i=0; i <= 4; i++)
{
    var hello="x1";
    create += '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>';
    for(ii=0; ii <= i; ii++){
        if(i==4 && ii==2){
            create += '<td class="'+map.y1.x1.type+'" align="center" valign="center"><img src="images/map/dot.gif"/></td>';
        }
        else{
            create += '<td class="'+map.y1.x2.type+'"/>';
        }
    }
    create += '</tr></table>';
}
for(x=4; x >= 0; x--)
{
    create += '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>';
    for(xx=0; xx < x; xx++){
        create += '<td class="'+map.y1.x2.type+'"/>';
    }
    create += '</tr></table>';
}
```

[Project Link.](http://wolftest.comxa.com/Map.zip)

Comment: Looks like a normal JavaScript object to me. http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: Please do not post questions twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you wrote:

> map.yi.yii.type

I assume you meant:

> map.yi.xii.type

If so, you could use concatenation inside square brackets.

```
map['y'+i]['x'+ii].type;
```

...so if `i == 1` and `ii == 3`, you'll effectively be doing:

```
map.y1.x3.type;
```

Comment: No sorry. I was just confused by the naming of the variable. Using `i` and `ii` just looks strange to me (because `ii` looks like a concatenation of `i`...).

Comment: @Felix - looking a the attached source code, the inner loop does indeed use `ii` as the inner loop variable. That threw me off cause I was thinking in roman numeral terms.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I wish I'd have figured that out earlier. I knew it would be something simple, and yes I confused the y and x.

Comment: @user440876: Once again (just to be sure ;)), the value in `map` is not JSON. You defined a plain JavaScript object using the object literal notation. JSON just looks similar as it is a subset of the object literal syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to do something like this:

```
map[y+i][x+ii]
```

Comment: I just get "y is not defined" in firebug =(